# When app is not opened and when i try to insert Data in Realm I get Error "Realm cannot be automatically updated on a thread > without a looper"?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to insert the data in my Realm DB through FCM push notification, now when `my app is opened` and when a push notification arrives there everything works fine, but when `my App is not opened` and when the notification arrives then when I tried to insert the data I got the error `

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Callback cannot be delivered on
>   current thread. Realm cannot be automatically updated on a thread
>   without a looper.

My **FCM** code

```
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                    story data = new story();
                    bgRealm.insertOrUpdate(data);
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    // Transaction was a success.
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
                }
            });
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I overcome this problem when my app is not opened ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync()
```

That causes the problem, instead you should use syncronious version.

```
realm.executeTransaction()
```

For async queries, you need a looper to make sure the query result can be delivered back on Android.